# Adding characters at the end of a string

Tags: c, string

I am trying to add some characters at the end of a string using the following code. I am not getting the desired output.

```
#include<stdio.h>        
#include<stdlib.h>       
#include<string.h>       
int main()   
{   
 int l,i;   
 char a[30];   
 printf("Enter \n");      
 scanf("%s",a);      
 l=strlen(a);      
 for(i=l;i<(29-l);i++)       
  {       
   scanf("%c",&a[i]);       
   a[i+1]='\0';      
   printf("\n%s",a);       
  }     
return 0;       
}
```

Comment: So what output are you getting, and what output do you want?

Comment: What output *are* you getting?

Comment: This code mostly works as I think it should: http://codepad.org/Z56p9SKx. What were you expecting?

Comment: Its working code. what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the problem is with whitespace. After you enter the first string, there is still a newline `\n` in the input buffer. When you then read one character with [`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), you get the newline and not the character you entered.

You can skip the whitespace, when you prefix the format string with a space

```
scanf(" %c",&a[i]);
```

Now it will append the character entered at the end of the string.

*Update:*

From [`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives which describe how to process the sequence of input characters.
>   ...
>   • A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.

This means, when you insert a space in the format string, it will skip all white-space in the input.

This will happen automatically with other input directives like `%s` or `%d`. But `%c` takes the next character, even if it is a white-space char. Therefore, if you want to skip white-space in this case, you must tell `scanf` by inserting a space in the format string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the input buffer problem. Now, what I am not able to understand is that how a space is solving our problem.